# A question concerning real quadratic forms- linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, quadratic-forms

> **Q.** For a quadratic form in $3$ variables over $\Bbb R$, let $r$ be the rank and $s$ be the signature. The number of possible pairs
> $(r,s)$ is$-$ $\quad$ (a) $13$, (b) $9$, (c) $10$, (d) $16.$

According to the question, $r\le 3.$ Since $s$ equals the number of positive eigenvalues minus that of negative ones, $s$ could be $3$ at most when $r=3$ and all the eigenvalues are positive. Furthermore, we have $s=p-(r-p)\Rightarrow s+r=2p$ (an even number) where $p$ denotes the index of the quadratic form. Thus, according to me, all the possible pairs are $(1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,3)$, and $(3,1).$ Among these, the pair $(1,3)$ is redundant. So, there are $4$ pairs in total. What am I missing?

Comment: The duplicate should do the job for you above. In your working, you missed the possibility of rank zero (all the squares in that case come from cross-terms).

Comment: @SeanRoberson If I follow the definition of "signature" that I was taught, then I am getting $6$ pairs, namely $(0,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,2), (3,1)$, and $(3,3).$ According to the suggested solution, the signature of a quadratic form is what I know as the index of the same. So, I guess the answer to this problem boils down to the definition of "signature." Sir, which definition do you follow?

Comment: Why can’t signature be $0$ or negative?

Comment: @TedShifrin In general, "signature" can be both $0$ and negative. In the present case, however, "signature" can be only $0$ as in $(2,0)$ which implies $1$ +ve eigenvalue, and $1$ -ve eigenvalue. Hopefully, I am not missing anything!

Comment: @TedShifrin My bad! I missed the pairs: $(1,-1), (2,-2), (3,-1)$ and $(3,-3).$ So, in total there are $10$ pairs now. This matches with option (c). Oh! My... Thanks...